# Google Script for spreadsheet to extract data from a PDF page linked on the sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, vba

I have a series of PDF files uploaded to Google Drive (and also stored on my computer here) in different rows of a Google or Excel spreadsheet. Each row has a distinct PDF file linked to it. What I want to figure out is a way to extract a 5 row of data (not a table) from the PDF and add it to certain columns on the sheet:

Here's a sample pdf:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j7pqeja38jxmzc/Sample.pdf?dl=0

The sheet looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/40u1n7umacd74kw/Sample%20sheet.xlsx?dl=0

So the process will be like Excel open linked file in Row 1, extracts data needed, then adds the data to certain columns in Excel/Google spreadsheet.

I was just wondering if this is possible.. The PDF has lots of pages, but I only need data from a single page in it.

If this doesn't work in Excel/Google spreadsheet, any suggestion how I can automate this process?

PS: I'm not asking for the exact way to do it, because I know that's a violation here, just wanted to know if this is something possible and can be done in Excel or Google spreadsheet. If not, any suggestion will greatly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it depends a lot on the PDF, which I imagine would be the biggest hurdle. You'll probably find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613809/get-pdf-attachments-from-gmail-as-text/26623198#26623198) is at least relevant, if not exactly what you're looking for.

Otherwise, if everything is stored in Drive, it's just a question of:

1) Looping through the sheet and opening the doc you want. 
2) Getting the content of the PDF (Probably as a string). 
3) Finding a consistent way to cut the relevant data from the PDF (This depends a lot on the content of the PDFs).
4) Pasting the data to the sheet.

Number 3 might be your biggest challenge, but once you get started you might find it to be a lot easier then you'd think.

Comment: Great resource! Thank you for that! Will take note of this.

Comment: Cool, if you've found the answer to be helpful, you can either upvote or accept it (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), depending on how much it helped, and I get fake internet points. Otherwise, feel free to ask another question, or for further information.