# Using GAS to overcome the max file size limit for Google Drive API Drive.Files.insert() method

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Does anybody have a clue how to use Google Apps Script (GAS) to overcome the max file size limit preventing the `.pdfToText()` function [@Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) [introduced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613809/get-pdf-attachments-from-gmail-as-text/26623198?noredirect=1#comment43053056_26623198) from converting a PDF of, say, more that 10 pages at a time?

The limitation is inherent to the `Drive.Files.insert()` method [documented here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert). This method occurs in line 58 of the `pdfToText.js` file [located here](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f).

Comment: Waitasec... the file size limit for insert() is 5 Terabytes - no 10 page PDF comes close. Is the limit somewhere else?

Comment: Ok, yes - since the conversion is being stored as a Google Doc, the limit that applies is documented [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603), basically 1M characters / 50MB. Still surprising that a 10pg doc would hit it. That step (line 58 converts PDF to a DOC on Drive) is where the real magic occurs, so it can't be skipped.

Comment: Maybe the web API from [here](https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-txt) could be scripted?

Comment: Check out [this tool](https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/apis/extracttext#overview)... I was having the same problem today at 10 pages (even commented on @Mogsdad's git about it before finding this post)... The API above solved my problem and is easily called by URLFetchApp in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from comments:

Per @mulliweht

> [Check out this tool](https://www.idolondemand.com/developer/apis/extracttext#overview)... I was having the same problem today at 10 pages (even commented on @Mogsdad's git about it before finding this post)... The API above solved my problem and is easily called by URLFetchApp in Google Apps Script.

Comment: this api is awesome! support almost all type of documents with easy api, and free!

Comment: can you provide an example of using the api?