# Is there a way to save a Gmail attachment as MP4?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to save a Gmail attachment as a MP4 file but I get this error:

> Exception: Converting from application/x-msdownload to video/mp4 is not supported. (line 138, file "Code")

Below the code:

```
function saveAttachment(attachment, path) {
  var parts = path.split('/');
  var file = parts.pop();
  var path = parts.join('/');
  
  var folder = getOrMakeFolder(path);
  var check = folder.getFilesByName(file);
  if(check.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' already exists. File not overwritten.');
    return;
  }
  var blobFile = attachment.copyBlob();
  var videoFile = blobFile.getAs('video/mp4')
  folder.createFile(VideoFile).setName(file);
  Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' saved.');
  Logger.log(attachment);
}
```

Comment: Are you applying this code to a specific attachment or all attachments in your inbox?

Comment: I do a loop of multiple attachments but this part of the code is the one used to save the file in GDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution in this topic:

[ERROR Get pdf-attachments from Gmail as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419877/error-get-pdf-attachments-from-gmail-as-text?rq=1)

The solution is:

```
function saveAttachment(attachment, path) {
  var parts = path.split('/');
  var file = parts.pop();
  var path = parts.join('/');
  
  var folder = getOrMakeFolder(path);
  var check = folder.getFilesByName(file);
  if(check.hasNext()) {
    Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' already exists. File not overwritten.');
    return;
  }
  var videoFile = attachment.setContentType("video/mp4");
  folder.createFile(videoFile).setName(file);
  Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' saved.');
  Logger.log(attachment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When looping through multiple attachements, you need to make sure that you only retrieve attachements of the right datatype, you can do it with an `if` statement:

```js
function saveAttachment(attachment/*, path*/) {
  var parts = path.split('/');
  var file = parts.pop();
  var path = parts.join('/');
  
  var folder = getOrMakeFolder(path);
  var check = folder.getFilesByName(file);
  if(check.hasNext()) {
  Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' already exists. File not overwritten.');
  return;
  }
 //check if the attachment is of the right type
  if(attachment.getContentType() == 'video/mp4'){
    var blobFile = attachment.copyBlob();
    var videoFile = blobFile.getAs('video/mp4')
    DriveApp.createFile(videoFile).setName("file");
    folder.createFile(VideoFile).setName(file);
    Logger.log(path + '/' + file + ' saved.');
    Logger.log(attachment);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to check if is a MP4 file first and then save it.